# window_mask for timedelta window for rolling list is ignoring first seen record

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have this modified rolling list that I need for specific test submission analysis. This is my modified code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Value": [5,10,5,5,10,5,5,5,15,5,5,10,15],
        "Time": ['2022-06-22 13:56:25',
        '2022-06-22 13:56:32',
        '2022-06-22 13:56:39',
        '2022-06-22 13:56:48',
        '2022-06-22 13:58:49',
        '2022-06-22 13:58:57',
        '2022-06-22 13:59:28',
        '2022-06-22 13:59:37',
        '2022-06-22 13:59:46',
        '2022-06-22 13:59:57',
        '2022-06-22 14:00:06',
        '2022-06-22 14:01:30',
        '2022-06-22 14:02:11'],
    }   
)
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(df.info(verbose=True))
print(df)
class ValueRollingList:
    def __init__(self,T='5T'):
        self.cur = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Value','Time'])
        self.window = pd.Timedelta(T)
        self.new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.last_window = list()

def __add(self, row):
    idx = self.cur.index.max()
    new_idx = idx+1 if idx==idx else 0
    self.cur.loc[new_idx] = row[['Value','Time']]
    
def handle_row(self, row):
    if len(self.cur) > 0:
        ## iterate through every unique Value except for 0
        self.cur = self.cur[~self.cur.Value.eq(0)]
        # create a time window of T and shape the original df to reflect
        # only the records within that time window
        window_mask = (row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs() <= self.window
        if ~window_mask.all():
            df = self.cur.loc[window_mask]
            if len(df)>0:
                df= df[~df.Time.isin(self.last_window)]
                if len(self.cur)==11:
                    print("**************")
                    print("self.cur")
                    print(self.cur)
                    print("df")
                    print(df)
                    print('self.last_window')
                    print(self.last_window)
                    print('window_mask')
                    print(window_mask)
                    print('self.window')
                    print(self.window)
                    print((row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs())
                    print((row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']))
                    print(row['Time'])
                    print(self.cur['Time'])
                    print("**************")
                df2=df[['Value']].value_counts().reset_index(inplace=False)
                df2.columns = ["Value","Count"]

                # Only record the time windows that have more than one record
                if len(df)>2:
                    print('#######################')
                    print(df['Time'])
                    print(len(df))
                    self.last_window = self.last_window + (df["Time"].tolist())
                    print('-------------------')
                    print("self.last_window count: %d" %(len(self.last_window)))
                    print('-------------------')
                    print("df count: %d"%(len(df)))
                    print(df['Time'])
                    print(df)
                    if len(df)>0:
                        self.new_df=pd.concat([self.new_df,df.tail(1).reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns='Value').join(df2.pivot_table(columns='Value').reset_index(drop=True),how='outer')])   
    self.__add(row)
    return

def dump_last(self):
    return self.new_df.reset_index(inplace=False).drop('index',axis=1).fillna(0)


# Instantiate the class that will count the unique values
# within the designated timeframe
rolling_list = ValueRollingList('5T')
s = df.apply(rolling_list.handle_row, axis=1)
#idx = s.index.max()
ValCountTimeWin_df = rolling_list.dump_last()
print("ValCountTimeWin_df")
print(ValCountTimeWin_df)
```

The following are the printouts that I'm getting:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 13 entries, 0 to 12
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Value   13 non-null     int64         
 1   Time    13 non-null     datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 336.0 bytes
None
    Value                Time
0       5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1      10 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2       5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3       5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4      10 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5       5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6       5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7       5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8      15 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9       5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10      5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
11     10 2022-06-22 14:01:30
12     15 2022-06-22 14:02:11
**************
self.cur
   Value                Time
0      5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     10 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2      5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3      5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     10 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8     15 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
df
   Value                Time
1     10 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2      5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3      5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     10 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8     15 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
self.last_window
[]
window_mask
0     False
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.window
0 days 00:05:00
0    0 days 00:05:05
1    0 days 00:04:58
2    0 days 00:04:51
3    0 days 00:04:42
4    0 days 00:02:41
5    0 days 00:02:33
6    0 days 00:02:02
7    0 days 00:01:53
8    0 days 00:01:44
9    0 days 00:01:33
10   0 days 00:01:24
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
0    0 days 00:05:05
1    0 days 00:04:58
2    0 days 00:04:51
3    0 days 00:04:42
4    0 days 00:02:41
5    0 days 00:02:33
6    0 days 00:02:02
7    0 days 00:01:53
8    0 days 00:01:44
9    0 days 00:01:33
10   0 days 00:01:24
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
2022-06-22 14:01:30
0    2022-06-22 13:56:25
1    2022-06-22 13:56:32
2    2022-06-22 13:56:39
3    2022-06-22 13:56:48
4    2022-06-22 13:58:49
5    2022-06-22 13:58:57
6    2022-06-22 13:59:28
7    2022-06-22 13:59:37
8    2022-06-22 13:59:46
9    2022-06-22 13:59:57
10   2022-06-22 14:00:06
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
**************
#######################
1    2022-06-22 13:56:32
2    2022-06-22 13:56:39
3    2022-06-22 13:56:48
4    2022-06-22 13:58:49
5    2022-06-22 13:58:57
6    2022-06-22 13:59:28
7    2022-06-22 13:59:37
8    2022-06-22 13:59:46
9    2022-06-22 13:59:57
10   2022-06-22 14:00:06
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
10
-------------------
self.last_window count: 10
-------------------
df count: 10
1    2022-06-22 13:56:32
2    2022-06-22 13:56:39
3    2022-06-22 13:56:48
4    2022-06-22 13:58:49
5    2022-06-22 13:58:57
6    2022-06-22 13:59:28
7    2022-06-22 13:59:37
8    2022-06-22 13:59:46
9    2022-06-22 13:59:57
10   2022-06-22 14:00:06
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
   Value                Time
1     10 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2      5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3      5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     10 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8     15 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
ValCountTimeWin_df
                 Time  5  10  15
0 2022-06-22 14:00:06  7   2   1
```

Ideally, my FINAL output should look like this:

```
ValCountTimeWin_df
                 Time  5  10  15
0 2022-06-22 14:00:06  8   2   1
```

I believe the problem lies with the `window_mask`:

```
window_mask
0     False
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
```

Looking at `self.cur` the first record should've been included but it is ignored because the window_mask says it's false. Why and how do I fix that?

```
self.cur
   Value                Time
0      5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     10 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2      5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3      5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     10 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8     15 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is `handle_row` function. In the first iteration of `handle_row` your `dataframe` `self.cur` is empty, therefore it just adds one row because `self.__add(row)` is called at the end, thus when you create the `window_mask` the row that is being evaluated and the rows that are being subtracted in the following line are not matching, so for the row with index 11 would be:

```
#             row.index = 11, self.cur.index = from 0 to 10
window_mask = (row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs() <= self.window
```

This means, the value of `Time` that is being evaluated is `2022-06-22 14:01:30`, since your `timedelta` is 5 minutes, the first row with `Time` = `2022-06-22 13:56:25` is out of the range of the 5 minutes you assigned to `self.window`. This is why you get `False` in the index `0`.

An extra problem that maybe you didn't notice before, is that you are missing to process one row, because you are ignoring the first line with `if len(self.cur) > 0:` since `len(self.cur)` would be `0` for the first row that is trying to be processed with the `df.apply()`

Another issue appears when you create the class attribute `df` (**Note:** I would suggest changing the name so you distinguish that it is the class attribute and not the original `dataframe`, even though they are in different `scopes` cold be confusing if you expand the class):

```
df = self.cur.loc[window_mask]
```

Since you are using `loc[window_mask]` this means it will only select the rows where `window_mask` is `True` but you are evaluating in the `self.cur` `dataframe` that is evaluating one index before (As we saw in the first paragraph), so you are selecting the following elements as you can see from your output:

```
1     10 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2      5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3      5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     10 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8     15 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
```

So when you calculate `ValCountTimeWin_df`, as you can see, you have only 7 rows with the value `5`.

### Fixing the issues:

At first, we have to be able to process all rows of the `dataframe` so we use `self.__add(row)` as the first line inside `handle_row` method. This will make sure that `self.cur` always processes the same data as the current row and avoid having the offset you had before.

To create the attribute `df` we will use `iloc` to be able to select all rows from 0 to the current row excluding it:

```
df = self.cur.iloc[:row.name]
```

Complete solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Value": [5,10,5,5,10,5,5,5,15,5,5,10,15],
        "Time": ['2022-06-22 13:56:25',
        '2022-06-22 13:56:32',
        '2022-06-22 13:56:39',
        '2022-06-22 13:56:48',
        '2022-06-22 13:58:49',
        '2022-06-22 13:58:57',
        '2022-06-22 13:59:28',
        '2022-06-22 13:59:37',
        '2022-06-22 13:59:46',
        '2022-06-22 13:59:57',
        '2022-06-22 14:00:06',
        '2022-06-22 14:01:30',
        '2022-06-22 14:02:11'],
    }   
)
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(df.info(verbose=True))
print(df)

class ValueRollingList:
    def __init__(self,T='5T'):
        self.cur = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Value','Time'])
        self.window = pd.Timedelta(T)
        self.new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.last_window = list()
    
    def __add(self, row):
        idx = self.cur.index.max()
        new_idx = idx+1 if idx==idx else 0
        self.cur.loc[new_idx] = row[['Value','Time']]
    
    def handle_row(self, row):
        # Add the row before anything else to make sure we process all rows
        self.__add(row)
        
        self.cur = self.cur[~self.cur.Value.eq(0)]
        
        window_mask = (row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs() <= self.window
        
        if ~window_mask.all():
            # Select all rows from 0 to one before the current row in "self.cur"
            # This would mean, process the rows from 0 to the current row (Including it) from the original data
            df = self.cur.iloc[:row.name]
            if len(df)>0:
                df= df[~df.Time.isin(self.last_window)]
                if len(self.cur)==11:
                    print("**************")
                    print("self.cur")
                    print(self.cur)
                    print("df")
                    print(df)
                    print('self.last_window')
                    print(self.last_window)
                    print('window_mask')
                    print(window_mask)
                    print('self.window')
                    print(self.window)
                    print((row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs())
                    print((row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']))
                    print(row['Time'])
                    print(self.cur['Time'])
                    print("**************")
                df2=df[['Value']].value_counts().reset_index(inplace=False)
                df2.columns = ["Value","Count"]

                # Only record the time windows that have more than one record
                if len(df)>2:
                    print('#######################')
                    print(df['Time'])
                    print(len(df))
                    self.last_window = self.last_window + (df["Time"].tolist())
                    print('-------------------')
                    print("self.last_window count: %d" %(len(self.last_window)))
                    print('-------------------')
                    print("df count: %d"%(len(df)))
                    print(df['Time'])
                    print(df)
                    if len(df)>0:
                        self.new_df=pd.concat([self.new_df,df.tail(1).reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns='Value').join(df2.pivot_table(columns='Value').reset_index(drop=True),how='outer')])   
        
        return
    
    def dump_last(self):
        return self.new_df.reset_index(inplace=False).drop('index',axis=1).fillna(0)
    
rolling_list = ValueRollingList('5T')
df.apply(rolling_list.handle_row, axis=1)
ValCountTimeWin_df = rolling_list.dump_last()
print("ValCountTimeWin_df")
print(ValCountTimeWin_df)
```

This returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 13 entries, 0 to 12
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Value   13 non-null     int64         
 1   Time    13 non-null     datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 336.0 bytes
None
    Value                Time
0       5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1      10 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2       5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3       5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4      10 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5       5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6       5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7       5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8      15 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9       5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10      5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
11     10 2022-06-22 14:01:30
12     15 2022-06-22 14:02:11
#######################
0    2022-06-22 13:56:25
1    2022-06-22 13:56:32
2    2022-06-22 13:56:39
3    2022-06-22 13:56:48
4    2022-06-22 13:58:49
5    2022-06-22 13:58:57
6    2022-06-22 13:59:28
7    2022-06-22 13:59:37
8    2022-06-22 13:59:46
9    2022-06-22 13:59:57
10   2022-06-22 14:00:06
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
11
-------------------
self.last_window count: 11
-------------------
df count: 11
0    2022-06-22 13:56:25
1    2022-06-22 13:56:32
2    2022-06-22 13:56:39
3    2022-06-22 13:56:48
4    2022-06-22 13:58:49
5    2022-06-22 13:58:57
6    2022-06-22 13:59:28
7    2022-06-22 13:59:37
8    2022-06-22 13:59:46
9    2022-06-22 13:59:57
10   2022-06-22 14:00:06
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
   Value                Time
0      5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     10 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2      5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3      5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     10 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8     15 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
ValCountTimeWin_df
                 Time  5  10  15
0 2022-06-22 14:00:06  8   2   1
```

Comment: You, good HeyTalePazguato, are amazing! Thank you so much!!! I should've realized that I was ignoring the first row.

Comment: I do have another question if you would be willing to help out a bit more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73418645/window-timedelta-not-recording-all-records    @TalePazguato