# window timedelta not recording all records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

This is in relations to a previous post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379529/window-mask-for-timedelta-window-for-rolling-list-is-ignoring-first-seen-record):

I am trying to build a set of analytics that would catch students sharing answers. I need to have the format so that I can create some nice plots that would show the results. Not only that but I need to have the evidence to back up my findings. Here, I am working on an analytic that would look at the challenges that a student answered within 5 minutes from each other.  I need the timedelta window of 5 minutes to ignore the times that have already been counted for. I have already scowled many pandas functions to see if there was something that would do the like of what I've been building from a modified version of a rolling list. I need the 5 minute window to be the span of one record back down to the second. My end goal is to have a dataframe looking like this:

```
ValCountTimeWin_df
                 Time   5   10
0 2022-06-22 14:00:06  11    0
1 2022-06-22 14:04:27   4    0
2 2022-06-22 14:15:08   4    0
3 2022-06-22 14:24:34   1    1
3 2022-06-22 14:26:49   0    2
```

I have a rolling class that should record a count for each of the various values seen within a timedelta window of 5 minutes.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Value": [0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10],
        "Time": ['2022-06-22 13:55:01',
                '2022-06-22 13:55:53',
                '2022-06-22 13:56:25',
                '2022-06-22 13:56:32',
                '2022-06-22 13:56:39',
                '2022-06-22 13:56:48',
                '2022-06-22 13:58:49',
                '2022-06-22 13:58:57',
                '2022-06-22 13:59:28',
                '2022-06-22 13:59:37',
                '2022-06-22 13:59:46',
                '2022-06-22 13:59:57',
                '2022-06-22 14:00:06',
                '2022-06-22 14:01:30',
                '2022-06-22 14:02:11',
                '2022-06-22 14:03:42',
                '2022-06-22 14:04:27',
                '2022-06-22 14:10:50',
                '2022-06-22 14:11:25',
                '2022-06-22 14:12:40',
                '2022-06-22 14:15:08',
                '2022-06-22 14:19:33',
                '2022-06-22 14:24:34',
                '2022-06-22 14:25:13',
                '2022-06-22 14:26:49',
                ],
    }   
)
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

class ValueRollingList:
    def __init__(self,T='5T'):
        self.cur = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Value','Time'])
        self.window = pd.Timedelta(T)
        self.last_window_mask = pd.Series()
        self.new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.last_window = list()
    
    def __add(self, row):
        idx = self.cur.index.max()
        new_idx = idx+1 if idx==idx else 0
        self.cur.loc[new_idx] = row[['Value','Time']]
    
    def handle_row(self, row):
        
        self.cur = self.cur[~self.cur.Value.eq(0)]
        # Add the row before anything else to make sure we process all rows
        self.__add(row)
        
        window_mask = (row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs() <= self.window
        print("...........")
        print("(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()")
        print((row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs())
        print("window_mask")
        print(window_mask)

        print("self.cur")
        print(self.cur)
        print("...........")

        if ~window_mask.all():
            # Select all rows from 0 to one before the current row in "self.cur"
            # This would mean, process the rows from 0 to the current row (Including it) from the original data
            df = self.cur.iloc[:row.name]
            df= df[~df.Time.isin(self.last_window)]
            print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
            if len(df)>0:
                df2=df[['Value']].value_counts().reset_index(inplace=False)
                df2.columns = ["Value","Count"]
                if len(self.last_window_mask)>0:
                    print(window_mask.value_counts()[True])
                    print(self.last_window_mask.value_counts()[True])
                    if self.last_window_mask.value_counts()[True]>window_mask.value_counts()[True]:
                        print("WOW")
                        #os._exit(os.EX_OK)

                # Only record the time windows that have more than one record
                if len(df)>2:
                    print('#######################')
                    print("row")
                    print(row)
                    #this is what will be added to the new df
                    print(self.cur.tail(1).reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns='Value').join(df2.pivot_table(columns='Value').reset_index(drop=True)))
                    print('#######################')
                    # add value count to the new df
                    self.new_df=pd.concat([self.new_df,df.tail(1).reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns='Value').join(df2.pivot_table(columns='Value').reset_index(drop=True),how='outer')])   
                    self.last_window = self.last_window + (df["Time"].tolist())
                self.last_window_mask = window_mask.copy()
            self.cur=self.cur.loc[window_mask]
        return
    
    def dump_last(self):
        return self.new_df.reset_index(inplace=False).drop('index',axis=1).fillna(0)
    
rolling_list = ValueRollingList('5T')
df.apply(rolling_list.handle_row, axis=1)
ValCountTimeWin_df = rolling_list.dump_last()
print("ValCountTimeWin_df")
print(ValCountTimeWin_df)
```

I know this will be a lot but I wanted to have full visual of what I'm seeing.The following are the printouts that I'm getting:

```
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     0 2022-06-22 13:55:01
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     0 2022-06-22 13:55:53
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days 00:00:07
1   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
1    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days 00:00:14
1   0 days 00:00:07
2   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2     5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days 00:00:23
1   0 days 00:00:16
2   0 days 00:00:09
3   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2     5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3     5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days 00:02:24
1   0 days 00:02:17
2   0 days 00:02:10
3   0 days 00:02:01
4   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2     5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3     5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days 00:02:32
1   0 days 00:02:25
2   0 days 00:02:18
3   0 days 00:02:09
4   0 days 00:00:08
5   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2     5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3     5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5     5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days 00:03:03
1   0 days 00:02:56
2   0 days 00:02:49
3   0 days 00:02:40
4   0 days 00:00:39
5   0 days 00:00:31
6   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2     5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3     5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5     5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6     5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days 00:03:12
1   0 days 00:03:05
2   0 days 00:02:58
3   0 days 00:02:49
4   0 days 00:00:48
5   0 days 00:00:40
6   0 days 00:00:09
7   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2     5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3     5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5     5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6     5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7     5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days 00:03:21
1   0 days 00:03:14
2   0 days 00:03:07
3   0 days 00:02:58
4   0 days 00:00:57
5   0 days 00:00:49
6   0 days 00:00:18
7   0 days 00:00:09
8   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2     5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3     5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5     5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6     5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7     5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8     5 2022-06-22 13:59:46
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0   0 days 00:03:32
1   0 days 00:03:25
2   0 days 00:03:18
3   0 days 00:03:09
4   0 days 00:01:08
5   0 days 00:01:00
6   0 days 00:00:29
7   0 days 00:00:20
8   0 days 00:00:11
9   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
9    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
  Value                Time
0     5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1     5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2     5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3     5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4     5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5     5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6     5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7     5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8     5 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9     5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0    0 days 00:03:41
1    0 days 00:03:34
2    0 days 00:03:27
3    0 days 00:03:18
4    0 days 00:01:17
5    0 days 00:01:09
6    0 days 00:00:38
7    0 days 00:00:29
8    0 days 00:00:20
9    0 days 00:00:09
10   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
10    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
0      5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1      5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2      5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3      5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4      5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8      5 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
0    0 days 00:05:05
1    0 days 00:04:58
2    0 days 00:04:51
3    0 days 00:04:42
4    0 days 00:02:41
5    0 days 00:02:33
6    0 days 00:02:02
7    0 days 00:01:53
8    0 days 00:01:44
9    0 days 00:01:33
10   0 days 00:01:24
11   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
0     False
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
0      5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
1      5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2      5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3      5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4      5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8      5 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
11     5 2022-06-22 14:01:30
...........
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
#######################
row
Value                      5
Time     2022-06-22 14:01:30
Name: 13, dtype: object
                 Time   5
0 2022-06-22 14:01:30  12
#######################
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
1    0 days 00:05:39
2    0 days 00:05:32
3    0 days 00:05:23
4    0 days 00:03:22
5    0 days 00:03:14
6    0 days 00:02:43
7    0 days 00:02:34
8    0 days 00:02:25
9    0 days 00:02:14
10   0 days 00:02:05
11   0 days 00:00:41
12   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
1      5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
2      5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
3      5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
4      5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8      5 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
11     5 2022-06-22 14:01:30
12     5 2022-06-22 14:02:11
...........
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
9
11
WOW
12
12
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
4    0 days 00:04:53
5    0 days 00:04:45
6    0 days 00:04:14
7    0 days 00:04:05
8    0 days 00:03:56
9    0 days 00:03:45
10   0 days 00:03:36
11   0 days 00:02:12
12   0 days 00:01:31
13   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
10    True
11    True
12    True
13    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
4      5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8      5 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
11     5 2022-06-22 14:01:30
12     5 2022-06-22 14:02:11
13     5 2022-06-22 14:03:42
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
4    0 days 00:05:38
5    0 days 00:05:30
6    0 days 00:04:59
7    0 days 00:04:50
8    0 days 00:04:41
9    0 days 00:04:30
10   0 days 00:04:21
11   0 days 00:02:57
12   0 days 00:02:16
13   0 days 00:00:45
14   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
4     False
5     False
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
4      5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
5      5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8      5 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
11     5 2022-06-22 14:01:30
12     5 2022-06-22 14:02:11
13     5 2022-06-22 14:03:42
14     5 2022-06-22 14:04:27
...........
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
9
9
#######################
row
Value                      5
Time     2022-06-22 14:04:27
Name: 16, dtype: object
                 Time  5
0 2022-06-22 14:04:27  3
#######################
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
6    0 days 00:11:22
7    0 days 00:11:13
8    0 days 00:11:04
9    0 days 00:10:53
10   0 days 00:10:44
11   0 days 00:09:20
12   0 days 00:08:39
13   0 days 00:07:08
14   0 days 00:06:23
15   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15     True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
6      5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
7      5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
8      5 2022-06-22 13:59:46
9      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
10     5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
11     5 2022-06-22 14:01:30
12     5 2022-06-22 14:02:11
13     5 2022-06-22 14:03:42
14     5 2022-06-22 14:04:27
15     5 2022-06-22 14:10:50
...........
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
1
9
WOW
10
11
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
15   0 days 00:00:35
16   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
15    True
16    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
15     5 2022-06-22 14:10:50
16     5 2022-06-22 14:11:25
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
15   0 days 00:01:50
16   0 days 00:01:15
17   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
15    True
16    True
17    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
15     5 2022-06-22 14:10:50
16     5 2022-06-22 14:11:25
17     5 2022-06-22 14:12:40
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
15   0 days 00:04:18
16   0 days 00:03:43
17   0 days 00:02:28
18   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
15    True
16    True
17    True
18    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
15     5 2022-06-22 14:10:50
16     5 2022-06-22 14:11:25
17     5 2022-06-22 14:12:40
18     5 2022-06-22 14:15:08
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
15   0 days 00:08:43
16   0 days 00:08:08
17   0 days 00:06:53
18   0 days 00:04:25
19   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
15    False
16    False
17    False
18     True
19     True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
15     5 2022-06-22 14:10:50
16     5 2022-06-22 14:11:25
17     5 2022-06-22 14:12:40
18     5 2022-06-22 14:15:08
19     5 2022-06-22 14:19:33
...........
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
2
1
#######################
row
Value                      5
Time     2022-06-22 14:19:33
Name: 21, dtype: object
                 Time  5
0 2022-06-22 14:19:33  5
#######################
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
18   0 days 00:09:26
19   0 days 00:05:01
20   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
18    False
19    False
20     True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
18     5 2022-06-22 14:15:08
19     5 2022-06-22 14:19:33
20    10 2022-06-22 14:24:34
...........
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
1
2
WOW
3
5
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
20   0 days 00:00:39
21   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
20    True
21    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
20    10 2022-06-22 14:24:34
21    10 2022-06-22 14:25:13
...........
...........
(row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs()
20   0 days 00:02:15
21   0 days 00:01:36
22   0 days 00:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
window_mask
20    True
21    True
22    True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
self.cur
   Value                Time
20    10 2022-06-22 14:24:34
21    10 2022-06-22 14:25:13
22    10 2022-06-22 14:26:49
...........
ValCountTimeWin_df
                 Time   5
0 2022-06-22 14:01:30  12
1 2022-06-22 14:04:27   3
2 2022-06-22 14:19:33   5
```

I believe there are a few issues in play.

The window_mask:we can see there can be cases when the new row being added causes two or more false instances and it being fewer in true instances than the previous iteration.This would then neglect the previous records that were marked as true previously.

Also, I'm noticing that the timedelta of 5 minutes in the first value count is going beyond the 5 minute window by 5 seconds. That's why the first record in the ValCountTimeWin_df is 12 instead of 11.

Another issue is that the last few records won't get recorded because there is not false instance.

Can anyone help me?

I NEED the solution to be in the form of a class that reflects this one.

Comment: Hi, could you maybe share the complete goal of your program? Because maybe could be done with `pandas` functions instead of building your own. Please also add the expected output so we can check what is going on.

Comment: Ok I'll do that. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Interesting question. Why is there no column for 0 in desired result? Aren't their two 0 values for the first window?

Comment: Yes there are but you can see that there is a if statement to remove the 0's. Those are start flags for sections and don't really need to be recorded.

Comment: Ok, why is first row timestamp `2022-06-22 14:01:30`? `2022-06-22 14:01:30` - `2022-06-22 13:56:25` is greater than 5 minutes so not all those value occurred ~within~ that window...

Comment: actually...it should be 11.

Comment: Should it be like this: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29719483/185694827-5be3462e-93a9-4ec1-a9bb-ab58c7a89b2d.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247394/discussion-between-cosmic-inquiry-and-daniel).

Comment: @HeytalePazguato do you have any suggestions? You were the one that solved the previous post with this formatted class.

Comment: @Daniel, sorry I have been busy at work. This is the type of questions that need to be checked carefully because it is a dedicated application, I have been answering other questions that are fast, I will have more time to check this one during the weekend in case you haven't got an answer by then.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato I appreciate your help! I fully understand where you're coming from. I have been trying to figure it out myself while I'm not giving a lecture, since this is work related. I think it has to do with the window mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I have found a viable solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Value": [0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10],
        "Time": ['2022-06-22 13:55:01',
                '2022-06-22 13:55:53',
                '2022-06-22 13:56:25',
                '2022-06-22 13:56:32',
                '2022-06-22 13:56:39',
                '2022-06-22 13:56:48',
                '2022-06-22 13:58:49',
                '2022-06-22 13:58:57',
                '2022-06-22 13:59:28',
                '2022-06-22 13:59:37',
                '2022-06-22 13:59:46',
                '2022-06-22 13:59:57',
                '2022-06-22 14:00:06',
                '2022-06-22 14:01:30',
                '2022-06-22 14:02:11',
                '2022-06-22 14:03:42',
                '2022-06-22 14:04:27',
                '2022-06-22 14:10:50',
                '2022-06-22 14:11:25',
                '2022-06-22 14:12:40',
                '2022-06-22 14:15:08',
                '2022-06-22 14:19:33',
                '2022-06-22 14:24:34',
                '2022-06-22 14:25:13',
                '2022-06-22 14:26:49',
                ],
    }   
)
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

class ValueRollingList:
    def __init__(self,T='5T'):
        self.cur = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Value','Time'])
        self.window = pd.Timedelta(T)
        self.last_window_mask = pd.Series()
        self.new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.last_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.last_window = list()
    
    def __add(self, row):
        idx = self.cur.index.max()
        new_idx = idx+1 if idx==idx else 0
        self.cur.loc[new_idx] = row[['Value','Time']]
    
    def handle_row(self, row):
        # This will handle each row and add it to the previous iteration
        # in order to implement the timedelta window of counting 
        # the values per student
        self.cur = self.cur[~self.cur.Value.eq(0)]
        # Add the row before anything else to make sure we process all rows
        self.__add(row)
        # remove the last window
        self.cur = self.remove_last_window(self.cur,self.last_window)
        # create a true/false series of identifying the records that are within the timedelta
        window_mask = (row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs() <= self.window
        # This would mean, process the rows from 0 to the current row (Including it) from the original data
        df = self.cur.iloc[:row.name]
        if ~window_mask.all():
            # Select all rows from 0 to one before the current row in "self.cur"
            df=self.cur.loc[window_mask]
            if len(df)>1:
                if len(self.last_window_mask)>0:
                    # if the last window mask had more true counts
                    # then process the last df instead of this one
                    if self.last_window_mask.value_counts()[True]>=window_mask.value_counts()[True]:
                        self.process(self.last_window_mask,self.last_df)
                        # now remove the last window from the last df
                        # and run the handle_row function again
                        self.cur = self.remove_last_window(df,self.last_window)
                        self.cur.drop(self.cur.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
                        self.handle_row(row)
                        #os._exit(os.EX_OK)
                    else:
                        self.process(window_mask,df)
        else:
            self.last_window_mask = window_mask.copy()
            self.last_df = df
        return

    def remove_last_window(self,df,last_window):
        # Return df with the times of last window removed
        return df[~df.Time.isin(last_window)]

    def process(self,window_mask,df):
        # Only record the time windows that have more than one record
        df2=df[['Value']].value_counts().reset_index(inplace=False)
        df2.columns = ["Value","Count"]
        #this is what will be added to the new df
        # add value count to the new df
        self.new_df=pd.concat([self.new_df,df.tail(1).reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns='Value').join(df2.pivot_table(columns='Value').reset_index(drop=True),how='outer')])   
        self.last_window = self.last_window + (df["Time"].tolist())
        self.last_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.last_window_mask = pd.Series()
        return
    
    def dump_last(self):
        return self.new_df.reset_index(inplace=False).drop('index',axis=1).fillna(0)
    
rolling_list = ValueRollingList('5T')
df.apply(rolling_list.handle_row, axis=1)
ValCountTimeWin_df = rolling_list.dump_last()
print("ValCountTimeWin_df")
print(ValCountTimeWin_df)
```

I had to breakdown the class into some extra functions because I realized that I needed to compensate for when the previous iteration of the rows was either equal to or greater than the current dataframe. If there was such a case, I would have to process the previous dataframe and remove the current row that was added and the rows that were processed before looping the dataframe back through the handle_row function.

The final output was this:

```
ValCountTimeWin_df
                 Time     5   10
0 2022-06-22 14:00:06  11.0  0.0
1 2022-06-22 14:04:27   4.0  0.0
2 2022-06-22 14:15:08   4.0  0.0
3 2022-06-22 14:25:13   0.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
agg_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Time"] + sorted(df.Value.unique())).set_index("Time")
piv = df.pivot("Time", "Value", "Value")
for s in piv.columns:
    frame = piv[s]
    frame = frame.dropna()
    windows = pd.Series(frame.index).diff().fillna(pd.to_timedelta(0)).cumsum()
    frame = frame.reset_index()
    while windows.min() >= pd.to_timedelta("0s"):
        win_5 = frame[
            (pd.to_timedelta("0s") <= windows) & (windows < pd.to_timedelta("5Min"))
        ]
        v = win_5[s].count()
        i = win_5["Time"].max()
        agg_df.loc[i, s] = v
        windows = windows - pd.to_timedelta("5Min")
        windows = windows.loc[windows > pd.to_timedelta("0s")]
        frame = frame.loc[windows.index]
agg_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df)
print(agg_df)
```

Output:

```
    Value                Time
0       0 2022-06-22 13:55:01
1       0 2022-06-22 13:55:53
2       5 2022-06-22 13:56:25
3       5 2022-06-22 13:56:32
4       5 2022-06-22 13:56:39
5       5 2022-06-22 13:56:48
6       5 2022-06-22 13:58:49
7       5 2022-06-22 13:58:57
8       5 2022-06-22 13:59:28
9       5 2022-06-22 13:59:37
10      5 2022-06-22 13:59:46
11      5 2022-06-22 13:59:57
12      5 2022-06-22 14:00:06
13      5 2022-06-22 14:01:30
14      5 2022-06-22 14:02:11
15      5 2022-06-22 14:03:42
16      5 2022-06-22 14:04:27
17      5 2022-06-22 14:10:50
18      5 2022-06-22 14:11:25
19      5 2022-06-22 14:12:40
20      5 2022-06-22 14:15:08
21      5 2022-06-22 14:19:33
22     10 2022-06-22 14:24:34
23     10 2022-06-22 14:25:13
24     10 2022-06-22 14:26:49
                     0   5   10
Time                           
2022-06-22 13:55:53   2   0   0
2022-06-22 14:00:06   0  11   0
2022-06-22 14:04:27   0   4   0
2022-06-22 14:10:50   0   1   0
2022-06-22 14:15:08   0   2   0
2022-06-22 14:19:33   0   1   0
2022-06-22 14:26:49   0   0   3
```

Should you want to exclude `Value==0` add this at the beginning:

```
df = df.loc[df.Value != 0]
```

If you want end values (in `agg_df`) greater than 1. Add this to the end:

```
agg_df = agg_df[agg_df > 1].dropna(how="all").fillna(0)
```

Basically, what this does is it says look at each value separately. Take where Value==5, start at `2022-06-22 13:56:25`. Consider the dates in the 5 minute window `2022-06-22 13:56:25 - 2022-06-22 14:01:25`, count the Value (11 in this case), then find the max timestamp in the window and add that in to the agg_df. Then subtract off 5 minutes from everywhere, so the next window is `2022-06-22 14:01:25 - 2022-06-22 14:06:25`, count the Value (4 in that window), add to agg_df with max TS, repeat the steps again until there's no more to chop off.

Move on to next Value, repeat...

Comment: Well, I am needing this to be still in the class format with the individual rows being the input. The application that I'm utilizing demands it.

Comment: I was hoping you could just help me fix the issue within my class..

Comment: also, the values can be dynamic and can vary from 5,10,15,20,25 in any combination of these.

Comment: do you not want to try again?